# problema en formula excel al representar su valor en js

Tags: javascript, excel

tengo una campo donde tengo un valor declarado fijo
la celda K6 contiene 25,60%

en otra contiene asignado un valor = ((K6+1)^(0,0833333333333333))-1
el cual toma el valor de la celda anterior y muestra como resultado 1,92%

intento replicar eso mismo en js en la consola pero me trae el siguiente resultado

```
var dato = 25.60 //enter
undefined
((dato+1)**(0.0833333333333333))-1  //operacion intentando replicar al excel 
0.31443809218123153 //resultado
```

¿cual podría ser el problema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que Excel esta realizando algunas conversiones que es tu caso no las estas teniendo en cuentas, para eso analicemos el proceso:

1. K6 es un datos de tipo porcentaje
2. (K6+1) = 25,60% + 1 ó 25,60% + 100% = 125,60%
3. 125,60% se convierte a decimal porque la potencia aplica a numeros decimales por lo que 125,60% = 12,56 decimal (12,56)^(0,0833333333333333)
4. Excel convierte nuevamente el dato del paso 3 a porcentaje por lo que el `- 1` equivale a `- 100%` = (paso 3)% - 100% = 1,92%

Mientras que en Javascrip todo es un decimal por lo que tienes que hacer las conversiones manuales dividiendo o multiplicando por 100.

Segun tu código para manejar todos los cálculos como decimal debemos de convertir la variable `dato` que es un porcentaje a decimal = dato/100, después el resultado calculoDecimal * 100 para convertirlo a porcentaje y obtener la respuesta que buscas.

```js
// Esta variable es un porcentaje no un decimal
var dato = 25.60;

// Convertimos la variable dato a decimal para simplificar las conversiones 
var calculoDecimal = (((dato/100 + 1)**0.0833333333333333)) - 1;

var calculoPorcentaje = calculoDecimal * 100;

// Redondeamos a 2 decimales
console.log(calculoPorcentaje.toFixed(2) + " %")
```